# Elastic search Custom Sort with Nest Library

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have a data structure like:

[image]

And I want to do so sorting to the results based on the **price** but for a specific priceProfileId ex 1292

I am using the nest library for that and my query looks like as below:
[image]

But its not sorting?

Addition Information: About ItemPrice Mapping

[image]

Comment: what does the mapping look like? Is `itemPrices` mapped as a `nested` type?

Comment: Yes Its nested, as shown in the image I have added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing is instead of the Price.Value I changed to Price and used .Order(SortOrder.Descending

Correct Code:

[image]